# From which book or essay are these words by Ralph Waldo Emerson? "Write it on your heart that every day is the best day in the year..."

Tags: poetry, quote-source, ralph-waldo-emerson

A funeral director proposed the following reading for a service. This poem by Emerson:

> Write it on your heart that every day is the best day in the year. He
> is rich who owns the day, and no one owns the day who allows it to be
> invaded with fret and anxiety. Finish every day and be done with it.
> You have done what you could. Some blunders and absurdities, no doubt
> crept in. Forget then as soon as you can, tomorrow is a new day; begin
> it well and serenely, with too high a spirit to be cumbered with your
> old nonsense. This new day is too dear, with its hopes and
> invitations, to waste a moment on the yesterdays.

I obtained from a library *The Collected Works of Ralph Waldo Emerson, Vol IX, Poems - A variorum Edition* and scanned the fat volume to find the name of this poem, and some background information. It was a fine introduction to Emerson's poetry, but now I look at the proposed text and it looks like it is taken from Emerson's prose. Emerson's poems do not look like this, although I was given a card on which these words were displayed in a more poemy fashion, center-justified.

Can you help me to pinpoint the source? Ideally, can you point me to the exact spot within Project Gutenberg (https://gutenberg.org/) so I can study the surrounding text?

Or is it a poem after all, and in my drowsyness, I have flipped past it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This passage is assembled (in the common fashion of inspirational texts) from bits and pieces, mostly but not entirely by Emerson. Let’s take it sentence by sentence.

> One of the illusions is that the present hour is not the critical, decisive hour. **Write it on your heart that every day is the best day in the year.** No man has learned anything rightly, until he knows that every day is Doomsday.
>
> <sub>Ralph Waldo Emerson (1870). [*Society and Solitude*, p. 157](https://archive.org/details/societyandsolit01emergoog/page/n164/mode/2up). Boston: Fields, Osgood.</sub>

> A farmer said “he should like to have all the land that joined his own.” Bonaparte, who had the same appetite, endeavored to make the Mediterranean a French lake. Czar Alexander was more expansive, and wished to call the Pacific *my ocean*; and the Americans were obliged to resist his attempts to make it a close sea. But if he had the earth for his pasture, and the sea for his pond, he would be a pauper still. **He** only **is rich who owns the day**. There is no king, rich man, fairy, or demon who possesses such power as that.
>
> <sub>[Emerson (1870), p. 150](https://archive.org/details/societyandsolit01emergoog/page/n158/mode/2up).</sub>

Note the omission of “only” from the assembled text, which significantly alters the sense.

> “He only is rich who owns the day” said Emerson; **and no one owns the day who allows it to be invaded with** worry and **fret and anxiety**.
>
> <sub>[Lilian Whiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilian_Whiting) (1900). [*The Spiritual Significance*, p. 105](https://archive.org/details/spiritualsignifi00whit/page/104/mode/2up). Boston: Little, Brown.</sub>

Whoever assembled the text seems to have found it unimportant to distinguish Emerson’s words from Whiting’s commentary.

The remainder, as [identified by Spagirl in the other answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/19418/3003), consists of fragments from a letter to Emerson’s daughter Ellen:

> You must finish a term & **finish every day, & be done with it** For manners, & for wise living, it is a vice to remember **You have done what you could — some blunders & absurdities no doubt crept in forget them as fast as you can tomorrow is a new day** You shall **begin it well & serenely**, & **with too high a spirit to be cumbered with your old nonsense This day** for all that is good & fair. It **is too dear with its hopes & invitations to waste a moment on the** rotten **yesterdays** Mr Cheney told me just now that Birdie had a capital letter from you.
>
> <sub>Ralph Waldo Emerson (8th April 1854). [Letter to Ellen Emerson](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.184814/page/n439/mode/2up). In Ralph L. Rusk, ed. (1939). *The Letters of Ralph Waldo Emerson*, volume IV, p. 439. New York: Columbia University Press.</sub>

Who assembled these fragments into the passage quoted in the question? The earliest instance I can find is in [Charles K. Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_K._Field) (1940), [*Cheerio’s Book of Days*, p. 146](https://archive.org/details/cheeriosbookofda00fiel/page/145/mode/2up).

Answer (score 5):

The lines were written in a letter to one of his daughters and appear on page 489 of volume II of ['A Memoir of Ralph Waldo Emerson by James Elliot Cabot'](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_Memoir_of_Ralph_Waldo_Emerson/JF8RAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0).

However, the extract quoted there is absent the first two lines, so either the letter to his daughter is reproduced elsewhere, that I have not been able to find, of they have been appended by someone else at some stage.

> To one of his daughters who was away from home,
> at school, he writes :
>
> “ Finish every day and be done with it. For manners and for wise living it is a vice to remember. You have done what you could ; some blunders and absurdities no doubt crept in ; forget them as soon as you can . To -morrow is a new day;
> you shall begin it well and serenely, and with too high a spirit to be cumbered with your old non sense. This day for all that is good and fair. It is too dear, with its hopes and invitations, to waste a moment on the rotten yesterdays. ”